# How to set a JSX element to a variable without return in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I'm trying to assign a variable which will be a JSX element in ReactJS.

I want to do it like that:

```
const [useResultText, setResultText] = useState('');
const changeState = () => {
    const br = <br />
    setResultText('Hello' + br + 'world');
}

return (
    <div onClick={changeState}>{useResultText}</div>
);
```

Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works fine, as JSX just represents certain kinds of JavaScript objects. But you have to define it properly:

```
const [useResultText, setResultText] = useState('');
const changeState = () => {
    const br = <br />
    setResultText(<React.Fragment>Hello{br}world</React.Fragment>);
}

return (
    <div onClick={changeState}>{useResultText}</div>
);
```

You might prefer something like a `p` or `span` tag over the fragment, depending on exactly what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there. Just set your state to an element:

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const Elem = () => <div>Some stuff</div>;
  const [useResultText, setResultText] = React.useState(Elem);
  const changeState = () => {
    const br = <br />;
    setResultText(<div>Hello {br} World</div>);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div onClick={changeState}>{useResultText}</div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

CS: https://codesandbox.io/s/vibrant-wind-0il8p?file=/src/App.js